# Ruby - str.upcase isn't working in a while loop

Tags: ruby, loops, while-loop, upcase

I've written code to take a string and return the same string back with all the letters changed to the next one and vowels uppercased.  However, when I try to run it, the vowels don't seem to uppercase like I expect.

This is my code:

```
def LetterChanges(str)        
    str = str.downcase.split (" ")

    str.each do |word|
        i = 0
        while i < word.length
            word[i] = word[i].next
            word[i].upcase! if word[i] =~ /[aeiou]/
            i += 1
        end
    end

    return str.join(" ")
end

LetterChanges("helo world")
```

Can anyone tell me why my code isn't working?

Comment: Can you submit the desired output for the example given?

Comment: @sagarpandya82 the desired output in this case would be "Ifmp xpsmE"

Answer (score 1):

When you access a part of a string via the `[]` method, you are returning a new string, rather than a pointer to that part part of the string.

You can see this by the following:

```
str = "abcdefgh"
str[5]              # "f"
str[5].upcase!      # "F"
str                 # "abcdefgh"
```

The `upcase!` method is working only on the new string, `f`, which is returned when you call `str[5]`.  Because it is a new string, separate from the original string, the original string remains unchanged.

Instead you can use something like:

```
def LetterChanges(str)
  str.gsub(/[aeiou]/) {|letter| letter.next.upcase }
end
```

Comment: Ah.... I understand now. So instead of gsub if I were to use `.each` it would still be the same string that gets modified

Comment: `gsub` is finding matches in the string based on the regex supplied to it.  The value returned by the block is what the match is being replaced with.  `gsub` is not modifying the original string but returning a new string with the matching bits replaced.

Answer (score 0):

```
def LetterChanges(str)
    str = str.downcase.split (" ")
    str.each do |word|
        i = 0
        while i < word.length       
            word[i] = word[i].next      
            word[i] = word[i].upcase! if word[i] =~ /[aeiou]/
            i += 1
        end
    end

    return str.join(" ")
end

LetterChanges("helo world")
```

will solve your proble...